# XGBoost predict function return more than size of target variable in r

Tags: r

I made the XGBoost model and when I try to run the predict function it return a vector with more than the size of target column in test dataset. 
Both train and test include the same categories of the target variable. Categories have the values of 0 to 7, so numerical and starting from 0. 
I tried different case studies as a pattern but the problem remains. Can you help  me to figure out what is causing this issue?

```
> head(train, 3)
       a      b    c   y  d   e
 1: 3.0148 4.4982  64  5  23  3
 2: 3.0011 4.4465  71  1  20  3
 3: 3.0084 4.4347  72  1  16  5
 ....
# 37 rows in train and 15 rows in test 
# store the target column of test and train data before deletion.
y.train <- train$y
y.test <- test$y
# remove target column
train <- select(train, -y)
test <- select(test, -y)
# change to matrix
trainMatrix <- as.matrix(train)
testMatrix <- as.matrix(test)
#find number of classes 
numberOfClasses <- unique(y.train) %>% length()
# XGBoost parameter set and run
param <- list("objective" = "multi:softprob",
          "eval_metric" = "mlogloss",
          "num_class" = numberOfClasses)
bst = xgboost(param=param, data = trainMatrix, label = y.train, nrounds=15)
#make the prediction
y_pred <- predict(bst, testMatrix)
length(y_pred) # returns 105 while there are only 15 rows in test data
```

Comment: Can you test with `y.train <- as.factor(train$y)` and `y.test <- as.factor(test$y)`. Usually  labels for classification problems are required to be of class `factor`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in your specification of the `objective` when training. According to the documentation (see `?xgb.train`):

> multi:softmax set xgboost to do multiclass classification using the
>   softmax objective. Class is represented by a number and should be
>   from 0 to tonum_class.
>
> multi:softprob same as softmax, but output a vector of **ndata * nclass**,
>   which can be further reshaped to ndata, nclass matrix. The result contains
>   predicted probabilities of each data point belonging to each class.

This explains why you are getting `15 * 7 = 105` elements in `y_pred`. Instead, you need to specify the objective as `multi::softmax` in `param`. This will return your 15 predicted labels.

Comment: Thank you very much. I spend many hours to figure out why this is happening. I tried different case studies as pattern but for all of them used the same param variable which I found in one of the examples. I sincerely appreciate your help.